# interact jade agents with jsp pages

Tags: jsp, agent, agents-jade

I want to **interact jade agents with jsp pages** which are available on my localhost. Everywhere I found agent communication when they are in LAN. My problem is that I want to interact and call the jsp pages, instead of plain agent<->agent communication.

I checked this **tutorial**

1. http://jade.tilab.com/doc/tutorials/JadeGateway.pdf

2.http://jade.tilab.com/doc/tutorials/jsp/JADE4JSP.html

but it was not much of help.....plz help

Answer (score -1):

Basically if the tutorial is not what you wanted. I think you are talking about web services where you communicate with jade agents via soap messages.

Take a look at these tutorials.

1) [Link1](http://agents.develop123.com/index.php/getting-started-with-jade/84-integrating-jade-and-web-services-part1)

2) [Link2](http://agents.develop123.com/index.php/getting-started-with-jade/87-integrating-jade-and-web-services-part2)

Comment: links are dead.